# Why cant I find /private/var/db/netinfo?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-tiger

I am trying to modify my users with dscl.  I have seen many people recommend that I backup netinfo before making modifications.  However, when I attempt to go back it up, i get this:

```
myserver:/ root# ls -al /private/var/db/
total 26648
drwxr-xr-x  36 root    wheel      1224 Aug  8 14:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  32 root    wheel      1088 Jul 24  2008 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel         1 Oct  9  2007 .ACLPkg
-rw-------   1 root    wheel         2 Jul 23  2008 .ApacheVersion
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel         0 Dec 18  2007 .AppleCustomMac
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel         0 Jul 23  2008 .AppleSetupDone
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel         0 Jul 23  2008 .AutoBindDone
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel         0 Dec 18  2007 .RunLanguageChooserToo
-rw-------   1 root    wheel         0 Jul 31 19:39 .SoftwareUpdateAtLogout
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel       674 Apr 27  2010 .com.apple.iokit.graphics
-rw-------   1 root    wheel     15360 Aug  8 14:48 .dashboardadvisory.database
-rw-------   1 root    wheel   2097152 Jun  1 14:45 BRLM.db
-rw-------   1 root    wheel     39992 Jun  1 14:45 BootCache.playlist
-rw-r--r--   1 root    admin      4598 Dec 18  2007 CodeEquivalenceCandidates
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel      4096 Jun  1 14:45 CodeEquivalenceDatabase
drwxrwx---   3 root    wheel       102 Nov 16  2008 DirectoryService
drwxrwxr-x   2 root    admin        68 Feb  4  2008 PanicReporter
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel       240 Dec 18  2007 PartNumber.plist
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel       102 Jul 23  2008 RemoteManagement
-rw-------   1 root    wheel        20 Aug  9 08:46 SystemEntropyCache
-r--------   1 root    wheel        48 Dec 18  2007 SystemKey
drwx------   4 root    wheel       136 Jul 23  2008 af
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel       102 Jul 23  2008 crls
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel     15360 Aug  8 14:48 dashboardadvisory.database
drwx------   3 root    wheel       102 Feb  4  2008 dhcpclient
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    wheel       170 Feb  4  2008 dslocal
drwxr-xr-x   9 root    wheel       306 Jul 23  2008 dyld
drwx------   8 root    wheel       272 Feb  4  2008 krb5kdc
-r--r--r--   1 nobody  wheel  11426199 Aug  4 03:21 locate.database
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel         7 May  1 08:50 ntp.drift
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    wheel       170 Oct  9  2007 openldap
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel       102 Jul 23  2008 samba
drwx------   3 root    wheel       102 Jul 23  2008 shadow
drwxr-xr-x   4 root    wheel       136 Sep 23  2007 squirrelmail
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel       256 Feb  4  2008 statd.status
drwx------   5 root    wheel       170 Jul 30  2010 sudo
```

I am using OSX Tiger:

```
myserver:/ root# uname -a
Darwin myserver.mydomain.com 9.1.1 Darwin Kernel Version 9.1.1: Fri Dec 14 19:00:14 PST 2007; root:xnu-1228.1.30~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your version of `xnu`, you're actually using Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard).

Compare e.g. the following from Apple's public open source software repository, both the last minor releases of their major version:

- OS X 10.4.11 (x86): http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-10411x86/ with xnu 792.25.20
- OS X 10.5.8: http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1058/ with xnu 1228.15.4

So you don't have [Netinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetInfo)  either:

> NetInfo is the system configuration database in NeXTSTEP and Mac OS X versions up through Mac OS X v10.4 "Tiger". [...] Mac OS X v10.4 is the last version to support Netinfo. Beginning with Mac OS X v10.5, Netinfo has been completely phased out and replaced by a new local search node named dslocal, which files are located in /var/db/dslocal/ and are standard property list (XML-based) files.

And your directory listing also includes the `dslocal` introduced with 10.5.

Comment: By the way, you really should update your server. It looks like an odd build of 10.5.2 or so, which indicates you never updated since you bought the device.

Comment: priceless information and advice.  Thank you much.  You are right, I should do update...